# Use WinSCP instead of CPanel

Tags: ip, winscp

I have a site http://www.example.com, the cPanel of which I access via the url/cPanel.

However, it is not accessible from the systems in my college as the access to the port through which it connects, something like 2082, is disallowed.

Is there any alternative to that, such as using WinSCP? Also, I only have the domain, not its IP address. I also have the username and password, that I use for accessing the cPanel.

Comment: Do you just want to transfer files? WinSCP is a program for transferring files (kind of like FTP, but over a SSH session); it can't do anything else. If you want to access cpanel, you would need to set up a proxy using a port your college's filter allows. You could do this within the server itself with some .htaccess + mod_rewrite magic

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Unfortunately this question is off topic here; SO deals with programming related questions. I've flagged this to be migrated to a more suitable site for you.

Comment: Yes. I need to transfer files.

Answer (score 4):

You can install WinSCP and transfer the files. To do so download and install WinSCP. Once it has been installed open it and select **files protocol** as **FTP** and in **Hostname** enter your **IP address**, same with **Username** and **Password**.  Now click on **Login** option. Once you are in you will be able to transfer files.

You can as well go though quick guide at : http://winscp.net/eng/docs/getting_started